# Using \href with with argument from a list

Tags: macros, lists, href

I would like to define a command that takes an input, passes through a list to generate another variable and then is fed to `\href` to give a link.
As in the following example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{forarray}


\DefineArrayVar{Names}{@}
{,}{aaa,bbb,ccc}
{,}{Einstein,Newton,Leibnitz}

\newcommand{\links}[1]
{\csname Names@#1\endcsname\
}

\newcommand*{\newhref}[1]{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\links{#1}}{\links{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Here is a page about \newhref{aaa}.

\end{document}
```

However the link I obtain is highlighted but doesn't link to anything.
What is going wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: show a complete example, that makes it much easier to test your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I included the \documentclass and end{document} commands. In the exemple above the word Einstein appears linked, but when clicking on it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `\` at the end of the line.

```latex
\newcommand{\links}[1]{\csname Names@#1\endcsname}
```

would solve the issue.

I'd use a friendlier way, though.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% define the array
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = items
  \prop_new:c { g_francesco_array_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_francesco_array_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
% generic command for retrieving a value
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarrayvalue}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = array item
  \prop_item:cn { g_francesco_array_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{Names}{
  aaa=Einstein,
  bbb=Newton,
  ccc=Leibnitz,
}

\newcommand*{\newhref}[1]{%
  \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\getarrayvalue{Names}{#1}}{\getarrayvalue{Names}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is a page about \newhref{aaa}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem!